# Why does this ASP.NET stack trace report two exceptions at the same time?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint, iis, stack-trace

On a Sharepoint site a user tries to repond once again to a survey he has already responded. IIS returns HTTP 500 and serves a page with the following error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
You are not allowed to respond again to this survey. 

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web  request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: You are not allowed to respond again to this survey.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 

[COMException (0x81020039): You are not allowed to respond again to this survey.]
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.IsVotingAllowed() +0
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.IsVotingAllowed() +174
[SPException: You are not allowed to respond again to this survey.]
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.IsVotingAllowed() +312
    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart.OnInit(EventArgs e) +955
    System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +143
    System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +271
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManagerControlCollection.AddWebPartHelper(WebPart webPart) +305
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManagerControlCollection.AddWebPart(WebPart webPart) +1930590
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManagerInternals.AddWebPart(WebPart webPart) +63
    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddWebPartWithRetry(WebPart webPart) +147
    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddDynamicWebPart(WebPart webPart) +122
    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CreateWebPartsFromRowSetData(Boolean onlyInitializeClosedWebParts) +12053
    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.LoadWebParts() +93
    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.OnPageInitComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +690
    System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
    System.Web.UI.Page.OnInitComplete(EventArgs e) +11038910
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1674
```

There're two exceptions reported in there - `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` and `SPException`.

How is that possible? What happened at ASP.NET level that two exceptions are reported at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is an inner exception of the other.

Comment: I guess `COMException` is the inner of `SPException`, isn't it?

Comment: @sharptooth - it has to be :-)